# ¿Cómo se denomina a los hijos de mis primos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, parentesco

Los hijos de mis hermanos son mis sobrinos. Pero ¿qué son los hijos de mis primos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Los hijos de los primos se denominan **sobrinos segundos** o también simplemente **sobrinos**. Efectivamente, el artículo [**sobrino**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YB8OOWc) del Diccionario de la lengua española recoge las dos acepciones (negritas mías):

> **sobrino, na**
>   Del lat. *sobrīnus* 'primo hermano'.
>   1. m. y f. Hijo del hermano de una persona.
>   2. m. y f. **sobrino segundo**.
>
> **sobrino, na segundo, da**
>   1. m. y f. **Hijo del primo de una persona.**

Comment: Yo tambien se que los hijos de mis primos (primos hermanos )son mis SOBRINOS, pero he escuchado de algunas personas que les dicen que son primos tambien y eso me parece extraño.