# Término: El/La medio/a hermano/a de mi medio/a hermano/a

Tags: solicitud-de-término, terminología, parentesco

Quisiera saber cuál es el término para referirse al medio/a hermano/a de mi medio/a hermano/a.
Ejemplo:

Juan y Emilia tienen una hija, Concha, después de un tiempo Juan y Emilia se separan. Juan se casa con María y tienen un hijo, Alberto. Emilia se casa con Ernesto y tienen una hija Susana.

Concha es media hermana de Alberto y viceversa.

Concha es media hermana de Susana y viceversa.

¿Cuál es el término para referirse a la relación familiar entre Susana y Alberto?

Comment: hermanstro o medio hermano segundo, como sucede con [los primos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28184/5481)?

Comment: Cuando dos personas tiene padres diferentes que además no son parientes lo más que pueden llegar a ser es amigos :) La existencia de Concha no tiene porqué influenciar el parentesco entre Susana y Alberto. Susana y Alberto no son nada entre si.

Comment: @DGaleano entonces la respuesta es que el término depende de la relación que exista, amigos o no, entre Susana y Alberto.

Comment: Relación, no parentesco..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada el planteo de las relaciones, se puede ver que Concha es medio hermana de ambos, pero entre  **Alberto** y **Susana** no hay filiación de ningún tipo. Aunque en la practica se los denomine así, por definición no serían hermanastros, al no tener relación de convivencia familiar.

```
 María   - Juan   ~|~   Emilia -   Ernesto 
   |        |  \         /    |         |
   |        |    Concha       |         |
    \      /                   \       /
    *Alberto* < [1/2 herm] > *Susana*
        |                       |
         >  *no comparten*     <
               filiación
```

No cubren el requisito de sangre o convivencia por union de sus padres.

Ver [esta explicación](https://significadoconcepto.com/hermanastro/)

> – Un padre y una madre tienen un hijo y, paralelamente, uno de los dos progenitores tienen otro hijo. Ambos descendientes **son medio hermanos**, porque comparten un progenitor.

> – En el caso de los hermanastros no hay ningún vínculo de sangre. **Cada uno de ellos tiene un padre y una madre de manera independiente.** El único elemento de unión es la convivencia o el matrimonio del padre de un hijo con la madre del otro hijo.

Comment: Alberto y Susana no son hermanastros porque para ello se requiere padrastro o madrastra, y Emilia no es madrastra de Alberto, ni Juan de Susana, xq Emilia y Juan no tiene relación matrimonial, error mío x no dejar claro las supuestas relaciones

Comment: Ah, cierto, la secuencia es importante, (no está bien representada la temporalidad ya que Juan y Emilia se separaron) y tampoco comparten el vivir con el padre o madre del otro (como dices no hay padrastros ni madrastras). Ya actualizo la contestación